# jasperreports studio - hard to get the column header to line up with the detail

Tags: jasper-reports

I have headers/details in the jasper reports studio. everything about this works wonderful minus one annoying thing I have to constantly line up the column headers with the details to make the alignments act correctly... even though i match the alignment exactly in the designer.

This is probably because I have a different font style on Header versus detail... or something? I'm not sure.

I can workaround the issue by manually tweaking X-coords, export the report, make sure they line up, until it looks nice... resulting in a designer like this:

[image: Shows the issue with alignment of header versus column]

Notice how I moved the values in the **Detail 1** band to the left so that the report with actual values lines up the columns correctly.

I must just be doing something wrong right? Why do I have to do this manual tweak to get things to look ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue when using Jaspersoft Studio.
I'd recommend you to use **iReport** instead, it's much more convenient for JRXML development and does not have this annoying issue in fields alignment.

Comment: Really? Man! That would really suck I love jasper studio

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the cells in "Detail 1" are set to display **centralized** text while the ones in the "Column Header" are **left aligned**. Try left aligning the text in the Detail 1's cells and see if things work out.

Comment: i'm sorry that is not correct. read the issue a little more and you'll see what i'm talking about.

Comment: Could you post your .jrxml? Hard to tell anything without a code.